# Источник комплиментов (с сервера, типа вики)

Tags: java, поиск-данных

Хочу в учебный проект добавить какуюнить странную фичу, типа - жмешь на кнопочку, получаешь комплиментик, или что-то в этом духе. Хочу для этих целей заюзать httpUrlConnectiob из se и gson для парсинга ответа. Знаю, что можно делать запросы на вики, но это немного не соответствует идее. Подскажите, может, есть какой-то сайт/сервер, где можно запрашивать комплиментики/мотивирующие штучки?? Важно, чтобы присутствовал сервер, иначе плохо представляется как парсить html))

Помимо этого, вход в приложение осуществляется с использованием гугл токена (если не через свой логин), и возможно было бы как-то с гугла получить "предпочтения" пользователя? Чтобы лучше подбирать контент, типа "ты круто играешь на гитаре!!"

Кратко вопрос звучит следующим образом:

1. Сервер/сайтик с милыми штучками
2. (доп если не лень) фильтрация контента с помощью гугла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть интересный АПИ для комплиментов и разных обидных штучек, вытянуть можно json -> https://insultgenerator.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/insult-collection/list-all-insults

Ещё один сервис, выдаёт рандомные комплименты -> https://complimentr.com/api

Насчёт предпочтений гугла.. Не думаю, что выйдет вытянуть предпочтения из токена, как бы там ни было, если найду что-то - дополню свой ответ.

Comment: Это даже больше, о чем я могла мечтать))) <3 Кажется, complimentr/api идеально подходит, но невозможно отказаться добавить еще одну кнопочку "поднять чувство собственного отстоинства". Спасибо!!)